# How to fix pygame flicker

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pygame, flicker

So I decided to try and make an application in pygame, due to more complexity than tkinter (it also helped that I was already using some of it) and I have come across a problem where only part of my text is flickering. (not all of the text on the screen just some of it)

Some environment info: I'm on windows 10 running python 3.7 on atom. I've tried isolating the problem but am unable to find where the problem originates, I have checked to see if it was atom by running the file normally but that didn't help.

```
import pygame
from winsound import Beep
from roundrects import aa_round_rect
from time import sleep, time
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
window_h = 725
window_w = 1300
bg_grey = (230, 230, 230)
button_grey = (190, 190, 190)
del_button_grey = (165, 165, 165)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
normalfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Aileron", 30)
mediumfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Aileron", 60)
largefont = pygame.font.SysFont("Aileron", 70)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_w, window_h))
morse_keystrokes = []
class Button: # this class will be used to draw and interact with a Button.
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, color, border=0, round=False, text=None, Font=mediumfont, Font_Color=black):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.color = color
        self.border = border
        self.round = round
        self.text = text
        self.Font = Font
        self.Font_Color = Font_Color
        self.draw()
    def draw(self):
        if self.round == False:
            if self.border != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
                pygame.draw.rect(window, black, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h), self.border)
                pygame.display.update()
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
                pygame.display.update()
        elif self.round == True:
            if self.border != 0:
                aa_round_rect(window, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h), black, 30, self.border, self.color)
                pygame.display.update()
            else:
                aa_round_rect(window, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h), self.color, 30)
                pygame.display.update()
        if self.text != None:
            self.draw_text()

    def clicked(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if self.x + self.w > mouse[0] > self.x and self.y + self.h > mouse[1] > self.y:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def draw_text(self):
        Label(self.text, self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, self.Font, self.Font_Color)


class Typing_Box:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, color, dbc, border=0, font=normalfont, typing_font=mediumfont, font_color=black):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.color = color
        self.dbc = dbc #delete button color
        self.border = border
        self.font = font
        self.typing_font = typing_font
        self.font_color = font_color
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        if self.border != 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
            pygame.draw.rect(window, black, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h), self.border)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.dbc, ((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15), self.y, self.w/15, self.h))
            pygame.draw.rect(window, black, ((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15), self.y, self.w/15, self.h), self.border)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.dbc, ((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15), self.y, self.w/15, self.h))
        Label("DEL", self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, self.font, self.font_color, (((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15)+((self.w/15)/2)), (self.y+(self.h/2))))
        Label("".join(morse_keystrokes), self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, self.font, self.font_color, ((self.x+((self.w/2)-(self.w/15)+35)), (self.y+(self.h/2)-10)))

    def update(self):
        if self.border != 0:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
            pygame.draw.rect(window, black, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h), self.border)
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.dbc, ((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15), self.y, self.w/15, self.h))
            pygame.draw.rect(window, black, ((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15), self.y, self.w/15, self.h), self.border)
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h))
            pygame.draw.rect(window, self.dbc, ((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15), self.y, self.w/15, self.h))
        Label("DEL", self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, self.font, self.font_color, (((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15)+((self.w/15)/2)), (self.y+(self.h/2))))
        Label("".join(morse_keystrokes), self.x, self.y, self.w, self.h, self.typing_font, self.font_color, ((self.x+((self.w/2)-(self.w/15)+35)), (self.y+(self.h/2)-10)))

    def clicked(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if ((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15)) + self.w > mouse[0] > ((window_w-self.x)-(self.w/15)) and self.y + self.h > mouse[1] > self.y:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class Label:
    def __init__(self, msg, x, y, w, h, font, font_color=black, alternate_center=None):
        self.msg = msg
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.font = font
        self.font_color = font_color
        self.alternate_center = alternate_center
        self.draw()

    def render(self):
        textsurface = self.font.render(self.msg, True, self.font_color)
        return textsurface, textsurface.get_rect()

    def draw(self):
        textsurf, textrect = self.render()
        if self.alternate_center == None:
            textrect.center = ((self.x+(self.w/2)-3), (self.y+(self.h/2)))
        else:
            textrect.center = self.alternate_center
        window.blit(textsurf, textrect)
        pygame.display.update()


def Play_Beep(Type, box):
    if Type == 1:
        morse_keystrokes.append(".")
        box.update()
        Beep(800, 300)
    elif Type == 2:
        morse_keystrokes.append("_")
        box.update()
        Beep(800, 600)

def first_screen():
    window.fill(bg_grey)
    dit = Button(20, 40, 450, 250, button_grey, 2, True, "Dit")
    da = Button(20, 370, 450, 250, button_grey, 2, True, "Da")
    first_box = Typing_Box(150, 667, 1000, 55, button_grey, del_button_grey, 2)
    back = Button(-2, 677, 80, 50, button_grey, 2, False, "Back", normalfont)
    run = True
    while run:
        first_box.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if dit.clicked():
                    Play_Beep(1, first_box)
                elif da.clicked():
                    Play_Beep(2, first_box)
                elif first_box.clicked():
                    start = time()
                    global morse_keystrokes
                    morse_keystrokes = morse_keystrokes[:-1]

first_screen()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
TIA

Comment: Please consider creating a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem. This will make it easier for folks to assist you with your problem. I would also suggest rearranging your code so that your main loop follows the handle events ⇒ update state ⇒ draw screen design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help but it turned out I was updating the screen a frame.

Answer (score 0):

These articles will be helpful.

[Flickering dice image when i press my dice button.](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/42rcbf/flickering_dice_image_when_i_press_my_dice_button/)

[Python Tkinter refresh canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21357178/9014308)

The following is an answer to tkinter's question, but it is similar to answer of pygame's question. I will quote this because it seems to be more concise.

> The only way for the canvas to refresh is for the event loop to service "redraw" events. In your loop you're never giving the event loop a chance to update, so you don't see any changes.
>
> The quick fix is to call `self.canvas.update_idletasks`, but that's just a hack and not a proper solution.
>
> The proper way to do animation is to use the event loop to do the iterations. You do this by placing work to be done on a queue -- in this case, the idle event queue. You can place things on this queue with the `after` command.
>
> What you should do is write a function that does one iteration of your animation. Essentially, take everything in your while loop and move it to a function. Then, arrange for that function to be continually be called as long as there is work to do. You can either place the call to `after` in that function, or have a separate function controlling the animation.